# When i use value in textarea i cant edit text, if i use defaultvalue i didnt have a value in textarea why?

Tags: reactjs, textarea

```
<textarea
    placeholder="Введите повестку дня"
    name={this.state.textarea}
    onChange={this.handleArea}
    className="uk-margin-small-top uk-margin-small-bottom uk-textarea prototextarea"
    innerRef={this.textFieldAgenda}
    value={!isUndefined(protocol.agenda) && !isNull(protocol.agenda) ? protocol.agenda : ''} />
```

How to use value for editing ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
componentDidMount() {
   var inputValue= !isUndefined(protocol.agenda) && !isNull(protocol.agenda) ? protocol.agenda : '';
   this.setState({agenda: inputValue});
}

handleArea= (e) => {
  this.setState({agenda: e.target.value});
}

<textarea
    placeholder="Введите повестку дня"
    name={this.state.textarea}
    onChange={this.handleArea}
    className="uk-margin-small-top uk-margin-small-bottom uk-textarea prototextarea"
    innerRef={this.textFieldAgenda}
    value={this.state.agenda} />
```

You will always get updated changed value in `this.state.agenda`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the values using [Default Values](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values) in react.

```
< textarea
...
defaultValue = {
  value
}

/>
```

Comment: It doesnt displayed

Comment: Sorry, i didnt get you @Badzillazavr